# Setting password for Django user

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm running Django and trying to create a superuser but I keep getting the following error whenever I try execute a passwd or createsuperuser command. I am using Django 1.3 on a PostgreSQL database.

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/stephen/.virtualenvs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/stephen/.virtualenvs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/stephen/.virtualenvs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/stephen/.virtualenvs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 229, in execute
    self.stdout.write(output)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

If I try passwd I get the useless stacktrace:

```
File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 134, in handle
    User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 140, in create_superuser
    u = self.create_user(username, email, password)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 136, in create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 570, in save_base
    created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/var/www/spurfly/master/apps/member/models.py", line 751, in create_profile
    profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 135, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 378, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 344, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 82, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 273, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 680, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/envs/s/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 44, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Here is my virtualenv.

```
$ pip freeze              
Django==1.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
mimeparse==0.1.3
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The way [I see it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) you have to call it either like this `python manage.py createsuperuser` or like this `python manage.py createsuperuser --username admin`. And assuming you have enabled `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo on my part. I was using `manage.py createsuperuser`, the command prompts me for username and password but fails to set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving wrong parameters. You should try:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --username=admin --email=a@dmin.com
```

Also:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/

Comment: Tried it with those parameters, it prompts me for a password for user `admin` and then throws the TypeError mentioned above.

Comment: So, what do you type for pasword?

Comment: I tried exact environment settings with you and it works well. I think there is a problem with your shell.

Comment: Did anyone else find out what was happening?
This is how I feel now...
http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: To the future:
This: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20856 was my issue (and probably something similar for OP )